# How do we want to tag Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning and other Kingdoms of Amalur games?

Tags: discussion, tags

[*Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning*](http://reckoning.amalur.com/), the first game in the *Kingdoms of Amalur* series is 2 months away from release. Since [kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning) is 28 characters, that wont do.

I see two choices:

1. [kingdoms-amalur-reckoning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-amalur-reckoning)

   - [kingdoms-amalur-mmorpg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-amalur-mmorpg)
   - [kingdoms-amalur-cooking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-amalur-cooking)
   - [kingdoms-amalur-cards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-amalur-cards)
   - [kingdoms-amalur-etc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-amalur-etc)
2. [amalur-reckoning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amalur-reckoning)

   - [amalur-mmorpg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amalur-mmorpg)
   - [amalur-cooking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amalur-cooking)
   - [amalur-cards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amalur-cards)
   - [amalur-etc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amalur-etc)

Answer (score 2):

Use the first style.

Should a new sequel require a tag name longer than 25, we can very easily switch to the second style.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with just: [amalur](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amalur) and deal with future releases (should they come out)?

Comment: We normally try to cram as much of the original name as possible in the tag.

Comment: @badp will we be redoing [tag:skyrim] then?

Comment: Answered my own question: [I guess not](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/rename-skyrim-elder-scrolls-skyrim)

Comment: I said "normally." We've determined that for Skyrim an exception was best. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEjZt0y6OOw&feature=player_detailpage#t=594s

Comment: Amalur is the setting, and _Reckoning_ is the actual game title.

Comment: 38 Studios has already announced that this is going to be a series of games. The other title in the works is the MMORPG, which doesn't have a name yet.